# Saving state with a struct in a c file

Tags: c, struct

I want to be able to access a struct variable from all functions in a .c file.
I assumed that the way is to declare the struct as static outside any function.
I have something like this:

```
static struct gameBoard current_game_board;

int foo() {
    current_game_board = { .x = 1, .y = 2 }
}
```

This shouts "expected expression before '{' token". When I try the same with and int instead of a struct gameBoard it works.
Is it even possible with a struct? Is there a better way to save state across a file?

Comment: Initializer lists are for initialization. This is _not_ an initialization. Set each member separately instead.

Comment: static here doesn't mean what you think it means. It means that the declaration and variable will only be visible in one compilation unit.

Comment: @UnderDog I want exactly that - a variable that will be seen only in the current file

Comment: @Jenian: Okay. That was certainly not clear from the problem statement. If thats what you want, static is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, that you essentially want a global structure you can write to wherever, then define the structure and create a global pointer to it. Allocate the pointer anywhere, and you can use it wherever you like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct gameBoard {
    int a;
    int b;
} gameBoard;

gameBoard *current_gameboard;    /* declare global pointer */

void prngameboard ()
{
    printf ("\ncurrent_gameboard-> a: %d\ncurrent_gameboard-> b: %d\n\n",
            current_gameboard-> a, current_gameboard-> b);
}

void setgameboard (int x, int y)
{
    current_gameboard-> a = x;
    current_gameboard-> b = y;
}

int main () {

    /* allocate memory for pointer */
    current_gameboard = malloc (sizeof *current_gameboard);

    current_gameboard-> a = 1;
    current_gameboard-> b = 2;

    prngameboard ();
    setgameboard (3, 4);
    prngameboard ();

    /* free memory allocated to pointer */
    if (current_gameboard)
        free (current_gameboard);

    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_global

current_gameboard-> a: 1
current_gameboard-> b: 2

current_gameboard-> a: 3
current_gameboard-> b: 4
```

**Note:** you should always check the return from `malloc` and test whether `current_gameboard` has been allocated before using it. Both have been omitted for brevity. let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

The Initializer list is for initializing objects. An Initialization is when you define a variable and explicitly assign it a value in the same go.
As you defined the variable outside the block already, you can't use an initializer list that way. Do this instead:

```
current_game_board.x = 1;
current_game_board.y = 2;
```

Also as @UnderDog pointed out, you are misunderstanding what `static` means. `static` for a variable at file scope denotes that it has internal linkage, i.e. it is restricted to the current translation unit and is not visible outside.

What you wanted is having the variable at file scope, which would work without the `static` qualifier too. You were right in choosing `static` though, as you should restrict access to everything that's not needed from outside. You just did it for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use:

```
static struct gameBoard current_game_board;

void foo(void) {
    current_game_board = (struct gameBoard){ .x = 1, .y = 2 };
}
```

This assigns a 'compound literal' of the appropriate type to your global variable.

A once-only alternative is:

```
static struct gameBoard current_game_board = { .x = 1, .y = 2 };
```

These require C99 or better support, but the fact that you're trying suggests that you probably have that.